# Eclipse RCP - Wrong plugin version is refered

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have eclipse rcp 4 application, which i migrating from mars to oxygen. It is a feature based application. All the required plugins are added to feature tab but some plugins like org.apache.batik.css, org.apache.batik.util and org.apache.batik.util.gui causing dependency issues. plugin tab by default taking 1.8 version of these plugins. But it seems that it has refer 1.7 version because if select only 1.7 from run configuration window application runs fine. Is there any way to make feature tab to select only 1.7 version instead of 1.8 permanently.? I tried to remove 1.8 version from eclipse plugin folder and it worked. But is there any better solution other than manually altering physical files?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen (which is ancient) uses version 1.8 of these plug-ins. You should work out what is refering to version 1.7 and see if it can be updated.

Comment: Some other batik plugins itself referring these plugins, They have mention as inclusive of 1.7 and exclusive of 1.8 and these conditions are also not changeable.

Comment: Sounds like you have plug-ins from different versions of Eclipse mixed together which isn't going to work.

Comment: This happened due to Birt 4.7 plugin. It is trying to refer 1.7 instead of 1.8. 
I installed it from https://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/oxygen-interim. 
If i look at different birt version they have dependency of some other batik version. 
Do any one know proper verion of birt report for eclipse oxygen 3a?